# Google GDPR message language

Tags: google-adsense, language

I've added the GDPR message in Google AdSense panel, but it detected my website is in Spanish so, Google has created the message in Spanish.

I've got Spanish as one of many languages in my website, but not the main language. Is it possible to add or change the message is it shown?

Comment: What is RGPD?   The only thing that I can find for it is it is the French acronym for General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR).

Comment: Yes, @StephenOstermiller, it's GDPR in english. It's my fault. I've wrote it as it appears me in spanish. Edited! Thanks!